# Rails grandchildren objects with :has_many, :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a schema structured as follows:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :foo_bar_bazs, :through => :foo_bars
end


class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  belongs_to :foo_bar
end

Class FooBarBaz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo_bar
end
```

I'm trying to do a select on the Foo model - like Foo.find(:all).  Both FooBar and FooBarBaz have the correct foreign key column in the database (foo_id and foo_bar_id, respectively).  So how do I access the child and grandchild objects when I access the grandparent object (Foo)?

In the end I need to be iterate through the Foo objects, then through the Foobar objects, then through the FoobarBaz objects, in three nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd revise the syntax to match convention:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :foo_bar_bazs, :through => :foo_bars
end


class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bar_bazs
  belongs_to :foo_bar
end

Class FooBarBaz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pc_scene_item
end
```

Now that we have the objects:

```
Foo.find(:all, :include => [:foo_bars, :foo_bar_bazs])
```

Now, :through can be avoided, and you can do:

```
foos = Foo.find(:all, :include => [{:foo_bars => [:foo_bar_bazs]}])
```

To get all children:

```
children = foos.collect{|f| f.foo_bars}.flatten.uniq
```

To get all grandchildren:

```
grandchildren = foos.collect{|f| f.foo_bars.collect{|b| b.foo_bar_bazs}}.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: When I try this: `Foo.find(:all, :include => [:foo_bars, :foo_bar_bazs])` or this: `foos = Foo.find(:all, :include => [{:foo_bars => [:foo_bar_bazs]}])` I get a "Association named 'foo_bar_bazs' was not found, perhaps you misspelled it' error...

Comment: The code is complaining that the association, has_many :foo_bar_bazs is not in the FooBar class. Please double check your models.

Comment: Ah, I got it!  Typo in the model.  Thanks very much, I was hung up on thi all day Friday.

Comment: @ssnkl it's good form to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use camel case to name your associations, but snake case:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :foo_bar_bazs, :through => :foo_bars
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bar_bazs
  belongs_to :foo
end

class FooBarBaz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo_bar
end
```

Comment: Nevermind that, I fixed it before you replied.  The only remaining question is how to access the grandchild objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake on your FooBar model.  I think you intended to say that it belongs_to Foo, not FooBar (currently you have FooBar belong to itself).

Assuming you have all the other data and relationship in place, you should be able to call it foo.foo_bar